# Cant figure out how to use .pipe(map()) to sort an observable array

Tags: angular, sorting, rxjs, observable

I am trying to efficiently sort an observable array without assigning a new observable to the current observable.

I have tried many different solutions but currently the closest I have gotten the closest using.

```
let testObvs$ = of([3, 5, 2, 1, 4]);
testObvs$.pipe(map(results => {
   return results.sort((a, b) => {
    let res = compare(a, b);
    return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
  })
}))

testObvs$.subscribe(e => console.log(e))
```

The expected result in the subscription [1,2,3,4,5] returned result [3,4,2,1,4]

I need the testObvs$ to be ordered based on direction. I have tested the compare and sort functions with a Number[] and they do return a normal array in the correct order.

I am using angular 8.2 and rxjs 6.4.0

The end goal for this sort was to sort an array of objects by a certain property like this.

```
 this.questions
        .pipe(
          map(results => {
            return results.sort((a, b) => {
              let res = compareString(a[column].replace(/<.*?>/g, ''), 
b[column].replace(/<.*?>/g, ''));
              debugger;
              return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
            })
          })
        ).subscribe();


export const compareString = ( a, b ) => {
if ( a < b ){
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a > b ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some issue with your implementation. Not sure what the compare method that you're calling here, is.

But you just need to return a `boolean` based on whether a number is greater than the next one. For numbers, it's pretty straightforward though. Here, take a look at the MDN Examples for [**`sort`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description).

Give this a try:

```
let testObvs$ = of([3, 5, 2, 1, 4]);
    testObvs$
      .pipe(
        map(results => {
          return results.sort((a, b) => (direction === "asc" ? a - b : b - a));
        })
      )
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Hey Sidd, Not sure if question is valid or not - If we have simply JS sort method why to use obserbable, pipe,map to do the same, isn't it? Even inside the function you have used the same which is `arrya.sort`

Comment: I just took from OPs example. I'm pretty sure OP was trying to learn something about Observables by trying them out on a simple array. Didn't really factor in the practicality of the situation here. 

Comment: @SiddAjmera You are very correct, I am trying to create a sort that can sort an array of objects by a selected property but at the time was stuck even sorting a simple observable array. I'm going to mark this as answered as you have answered my question. Still stuck implementing the same code to an array of objects sadly.

I'll update my question a bit just to add the code involving objects if you are keen to help still.